# dtype of the "Planted date" in the dataset was object. I want to change the dtype to datetime. I used parse_dates to convert but it doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, altair

I want to change the dtype to datetime. I used `parse_dates` to convert, but it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy as np

t_data = pd.read_csv('../TreesEdmonton.csv', parse_dates = ['PLANTED_DATE'])
t_data
```

[This shows the data has been transformed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2xrJ.png)

[t_data.info() shows the dtype still object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpSu1.png)

here is the link to download the csv file,
https://data.edmonton.ca/Environmental-Services/Trees/eecg-fc54/data

Appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_dates` will fail quietly if it is unable to parse the dates.

You can see the error by parsing the dates manually after loading the dataframe:

```python
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.PLANTED_DATE)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1190-05-25 00:00:00
```

Several entries in the dataset have dates that are too old for the default datetime64 representation.

One way you can get around this is to use `errors='coerce'`, which will replace the problematic times with `NaT`:

```python
>>> df.PLANTED_DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.PLANTED_DATE, errors='coerce')
>>> df.PLANTED_DATE.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

It now has a date-like dtype.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I am very new to subject. Thank you very much for your help